# Pandas and regular expressions

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the code below hoping to accomplish simple pattern recognition. I want it to find all occurences of PDP or CDP or PRS or EDP followed by (0 or up to 3) nondigits followed by (exactly 6 digits). Seems simple enough but pandas keeps screaming the error below.

sample rows of data:

```
row1 CAPS ACCT # /APR 1-APR 30 18/EDP 443996/SPECIAL PRICING
row2 CAPS /EDP# 320902/UNUSED LABELS


ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

df['USPS_refund_no'] = df['APEX Invoice Description'].str.extract(r'((EDP)|(PDP)|(CDP)|(PRS)\D{,3}\d{6})',expand=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `expand=True`, it is trying to return 5 columns, but you are assigning it to a single column. Try `expand=False`, see if you can work with that output

Comment: What does your Invoice Description look like? Post sample df

Comment: expand = False gives same error

Comment: You need to use `r'(EDP|PDP|CDP|PRS\D{0,3}\d{6})'`, just 1 capturing group. Also, always specify the lower bound for the limiting quantifier, `{0,3}`, since `{,3}` may not always work across regex libraries.

Comment: I'm no longer getting the error but it's only matching the EDP, PDP, CDP; it's not capturing the trailing digits. Only one case was matched included the numbers and it was PRSDP # 437036. Many were missed.

Comment: That sounds like another issue. Probably, you want to match any amount of non-digits, replace `PRS\D{0,3}\d{6}` with `PRS\D*\d+`. What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: Do you mean there must always be a number after a list of substrings? `r'((?:EDP|PDP|CDP|PRS)\D{0,3}\d{6})'`?

Comment: Any of and only one of EDP, PDP, CDP, PRS; followed by 0 to 5 non-digits; followed by exactly 6 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `str.extract` expects one capturing group. To match alternatives before the number, enclose the alternative list with a non-capturing group and capture the whole pattern with an outer capturing group:

```
df['USPS_refund_no'] = df['APEX Invoice Description'].str.extract(r'((?:EDP|PDP|CDP|PRS)\D{0,3}\d{6})',expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMkuRV/2).

**Details**

- `(` - start of the outer capturing group (required for `extract`)
- `(?:EDP|PDP|CDP|PRS)` - a non-capturing group matching any one of the alternatives listed inside (note you may also write it as `(?:[EPC]DP|PRS)`):

  - `EDP` - `EDP`
  - `|` - or
  - `PDP` - `PDP`
  - `|` - or
  - `CDP` - `CDP`
  - `|` - or
  - `PRS` - `PRS`
- `\D{0,3}` - 0 to 3 non-digits
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `)` - end of the outer capturing group.

Comment: That did it Wiktor. Thanks for all of your help.